# Cinnabar decomposition by heating optional method?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, heat, oxidation-state, mercury

Is it possible to decompose cinnabar into $\ce{Hg}$ and $\ce{S}$ instead of $\ce{Hg + SO2}$ with roasting and heating. What conditions need to be satisfied in the new method?

Comment: New method for what? Sulfur is inexpensive and would never be made from HgS decomposition. Mercury is obtained this way, by roasting cinnabar. But there is already a surplus of mercury world-wide. So what is the point?

Comment: Even though the chemistry is often not about *why*, but rather about *why not*, I agree with @EdV that obtaining elements from mercury(II) sulfide is not economically feasible. By the way, is you read Russian (judging from your nickname), feel free to have a look at the reactions for HgS listed in Лидин, Р. А.; Молочко, В. А.; Андреева, Л. Л. *Химические Свойства Неорганических Веществ*, 3rd ed.; Химия: Москва, **2000**. This should give an idea what can be done easily and what not so.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to fully decompose cinnabar to elemental mercury and sulfur.

> What conditions need to be satisfied in the new method?

Before reaching to decomposition temperature, cinnabar phase transitions to a different polymorph. Data from this paper<sup>1</sup> indicate that α-HgS (trigonal) → β-HgS (cubic) phase transition occurs at 673 K and is completed at 698 K. The thermal expansion of cinnabar is fairly isotropic. At 744 K, the thermal decomposition of HgS occurs to elemental mercury and sulfur accompanied by a change in mechanism<sup>2</sup>.

> So, is this decomposition technique feasible for producing mercury?

Not really, because you have to achieve very high temperature for cinnabar to fully decompose. Then, you have to separate mercury and sulfur from the mixture which is again additional work.

So, basically [roasting process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roasting_(metallurgy)) is applied. In this case, crushed cinnabar ore is roasted in rotary furnaces. Pure mercury separates from sulfur in this process and easily evaporates. A condensing column is used to collect the liquid metal, which is most often shipped in iron flasks. If the ore is heated in an atmosphere of oxygen, then mercuric oxide is formed which gets decomposed to mercury (which is deposited below while the gases escape). The other advantages is that the roasting temperature is lower than the decomposition temperature, so it is easy to achieve.

$$\ce{2HgS + 3O2 -> 2HgO + 2SO2 ^}$$

$$\ce{2HgO + HgS -> 3Hg + SO2 ^}$$

$$\ce{2HgO ->[\Delta] 2Hg + O2 ^}$$

Another technique is to heat cinnabar in an atmosphere of hydrogen. The sulfur that is forming quickly reacts with hydrogen to form hydrogen sulfide which escape as a gas. Simultaneously, hydrogen helps in the reduction of cinnabar and the process quickly accelerates to completion.

$$\ce{HgS + H2 ->[\Delta] Hg + H2S ^}$$

**References**

1. Ballirano, Paolo & Botticelli, Michela & Maras, Adriana. (**2013**). Thermal behaviour of cinnabar, α-HgS, and the kinetics of the β-HgS (metacinnabar) → α HgS conversion at room temperature. European Journal of Mineralogy. 25. 957-965. [10.1127/0935-1221/2013/0025-2341.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268518431_Thermal_behaviour_of_cinnabar_a-HgS_and_the_kinetics_of_the_b-HgS_metacinnabar_a_HgS_conversion_at_room_temperature)
2. Baláž, P., Godočiková, E. Thermal Reduction of Mechanically Activated Cinnabar (HgS) and Stibnite (Sb2S3). Journal of Thermal Analysis and Calorimetry 65, 51–57 (**2001**). [https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1011564232088](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1011564232088)

Comment: (+1) Your usual thorough and nice work!